# How to change hostname lookup engine in Denyhosts?

Tags: ubuntu, lookup

I would like to use my own script to determine IP location for blocked hosts but I do not know how to proceed. The IP location is needed for me to add this information to my mail notification.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.

In denyhosts.conf file we can find option

> HOSTNAME_LOOKUP=YES|NO

but we do not have any option to add my own bash script.

I would like to have information at blocked IPs.

Comment: Seems like you want to disable HOSTNAME_LOOKUP so you can use the IP address. Is setting the flag to NO an option?

Comment: @Ryan, HOSTNAME_LOOKUP = YES currently but it not works acceptable for me, so I want to use my own script.